# Swipe gesture for container widgets

Tags: flutter, containers, carousel, swipe, swiper.js

I want to create an Instagram like carousel effect with container widgets inside Flutter. I tried the "swiper_flutter" plugin but could´nt achieve the effect I wanted. You can see the sketch I've made here.

[image]

I want it to switch the content by detecting a swipe gesture. I also thought of giving the "cards" an index so it can show the count of the pages on the dots below. But I just can't figure out how to swap the container by detecting a swipe gesture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PageView and the onPageChanged to re-render after scrolling

```
PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: {Your items},
        onPageChanged: (int index) => onPressCallback(
            {Your code here}
      )
```